# Can I keep on same jQuery tab on page refresh or when I have navigated away from the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I have a basic jQuery tabs system going:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs div.jdiv').hide();
  $('#tabs div.jdiv:first').fadeIn("slow");
  $('#tabs ul.jdiv li:first').addClass('active');
  $('#tabs ul.jdiv li a').click(function(){ 
    $('#tabs ul.jdiv li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $('#tabs div.jdiv').hide();
    $(currentTab).fadeIn("slow");
  return false;
  });
});

<div id="tabs" style="position:relative; ">
                <ul class="jdiv">
                  <li><a href="#current-points">Current Points</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#my-details">My Details</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#prizes">Prizes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#basket">Your sack</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#order-history">Order History</a></li>

                </ul>

            <div id="current-points" class="jdiv" style="position:relative;">
                <?php include('current-points.php');?>     
            </div>
```

etc....

My issue is, I am planning on having another set of jQuery tabs within one of these pages, which isnt a problem, but when they click on a link or refresh the page, is it possible to stay on the same tab? On the parent or child set of tabs?

Thanks!

Comment: Im not using a tab specific plugin, just regular jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use hash tags to uniquely identify each tab, so `http://example.com/yourpage.html#current-points` takes you to the `current-points` tab, and `http://example.com/yourpage.html#my-details` takes you to the `my-details` tab. You can set the hash by assigning to `location.hash`, and of course you can read that on page load. This also has the huge advantage that your users can bookmark the tabs they want. You can use a path in the hash if you have tabs within tabs (so `#first/foo` takes you to the `first` tab and its `foo` subtab; `#first/bar` takes you to the `first` tab and its `bar` subtab).

Here's a really basic example (without subtabs, but you get the idea):

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ugapax) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ugapax/edit)

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third">Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab" id="tab-first">This is first</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab-second">This is second</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab-third">This is third</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("<p>").html("Loaded at " + new Date()).appendTo(
        document.body
    );
    showTab(location.hash || "first");

    $("#nav a").click(function() {
        var hash = this.getAttribute("href");
        if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
            hash = hash.substring(1);
        }
        location.hash = hash;
        showTab(hash);
        return false;
    });

    function showTab(hash) {
        $("div.tab").hide();
        $("#tab-" + hash).show();
    }

});
```

Alternately (or in conjunction), you can set a cookie when they change tabs, and check for the cookie on page load to select the last tab they had selected.

Comment: Ok this is brill, thanks. A much better tab system than I had originally.

Comment: Just wondering... I am trying to set a cookie when the user switches tabs... will this need to be done through javascript or just in PHP?

Comment: @JamesG: I didn't see any calls to the server in your tabs stuff, so you'd do it with JavaScript. Browsers expose cookies to JavaScript is a **very** strange way, but there are cookie plug-ins to jQuery ([like this one](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)) that will handle any complexity for you, or you can grab some code from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) (it also has a reasonable write-up of how the JavaScript interface to them works).

Comment: Ok thanks! Didnt even know about cookies with JS... such a noob sorry. Appreciate it!

Comment: awesome, many thanks. We had this issue with refresh since ages and finally it is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the current tab open after the page is refreshed only solution coming in my mind is using cookies, I think it's the only one.

If you use a link in the web page, on the other hand, to refresh the page you could add an anchor to it with the tab opened at the time.

Answer (score -1):

Not easily. The client side script is reloaded when you refresh the page, and all changes will be undone, unless of course you store it somewhere — possibly as a URL parameter?

Comment: Ok, souinds reasonable. I just assumed it would be a common problem that there is a definite solution for. Ill try the URL parameter. Thanks