# any way to stay in the same location when refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am working on jquery and javascript. and is there any way to make the page refresh and to restore the same link which is clicked. for example. in gmail.com when we open sent items which is in the lefthand side of the window and refresh the page. it get reloaded with the same sent items tab's contents, same things work for inbox and drafts when refreshed. is there anyother method or example to acheive this. if yes. please help. it would be appreciated.

here is my code to make the page refresh on refresh:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function(){
  $(function()
   {
    $('#submit').click(function()
      { 
          $('.container').show();
          $('#login').hide();
            $.cookie('shown', true);
            });
          if ($.cookie('shown')) {
              $('#submit').click()
          }
        });
     });  

   </script>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? It allows you to update part of the apge without doing a full refresh. That's what GMail uses

Comment: [Refer This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497320/can-i-keep-on-same-jquery-tab-on-page-refresh-or-when-i-have-navigated-away-from)

Comment: @Basic: no i think that is not the case. when we refresh the whole page the tab which is opened before refreshing must be re-opened. and no the tab which usually loads at the start should be visible.

Comment: Ah ok, In that case, @drarkayl's got the right answer - Use the value after a hash in the url to indicate what should be reloaded.

Comment: either use `AJAX` or `SESSION`

Comment: @loy: any examples please.

Comment: @drarkayl: the question which you gave was for php. is there any way to work around that same with Javascript.?

Comment: @NaughtyProgrammer can you please show me where php was used? that link is with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample ajax form submit script.

```
// this is the id of the submit button
$("#submit").click(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: i am working on javascript and not in php. and also i am refreshing a page where the selected link must reload even though the page got refreshed.

Comment: so how you gonna submit your data?

Comment: right now i am jus making this thing to be performed using button click action. i ll even gve you the fiddle link.: http://jsfiddle.net/PzKUh/8/. in this link it does not open the associates links. but the thing which i try is to click the link after that if i refresh i should no go back to the page which contained that ahref's. it should be the selected link.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you're using Ajax to change your page states, why not look at something like [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)?