# Jquery Tab should remain unchanged after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs

I am new to Jquery. I am facing a problem with tab implementation. When I refresh the page I am getting redirected to the intial set tab.

```
$(function() {
            var indicator = $('#indicator'),
            indicatorHalfWidth = indicator.width()/2,
            lis = $('#tabs').children('li');

            $("#tabs").tabs("#content section", {
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeOutSpeed: 0,
                fadeInSpeed: 400,
                onBeforeClick: function(event, index) {
                    var li = lis.eq(index),
                    newPos = li.position().left + (li.width()/2) - indicatorHalfWidth;
                    indicator.stop(true).animate({ left: newPos }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
                }
            }); 

            });
```

This is HTML VIEW :

```
<nav>
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a class "current" t" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Update Your Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<span id="indicator"></span>
</nav>
<div id="content">
    <section>
    <!--content1 -->
    </section>
    <section>
    <!--content2-->
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. Here are two ways to do:

1. You can use hash tags that are well explained in below post

[Can I keep on same jQuery tab on page refresh or when I have navigated away from the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497320/can-i-keep-on-same-jquery-tab-on-page-refresh-or-when-i-have-navigated-away-from)

2. Initialize a tabs with the cookie option specified.

`$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });`