# Remaining on same Tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

i have a tab menu that has a different section within I.E to do list , file upload , notepad however when you for example add a task to the to do list on submit the page then refreshes back to Tab 1 when i want this to stay on the same tab

here is my current code for the tab menu

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1">
            @include('includes/_tasks')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3">
            @include('includes/_notes')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-4">
            @include('includes/_file_upload')
        </div>
        <!--            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                        @include('includes/_github')
                    </div>-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello @dan, Could you please upvote the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporary save the last active tab index in one object (Or you can use cookie as well) and after page refresh, you first find tab index from that object. If it contains any value then apply active class to that tab. Otherwise it will be on first tab by default.

Comment: how would i go about this tried looking into this but so many ways

Comment: Which framework or backend technology you are using?

Comment: im using laravel 5.3

Comment: I am not aware about larawel. BUt you can take a look on below url. It may help you :).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497320/can-i-keep-on-same-jquery-tab-on-page-refresh-or-when-i-have-navigated-away-from